# Why is the request user null in my logout function?

Tags: laravel, api, oauth, laravel-passport

I am implementing an Authentication api in Laravel using *passport*.

I have implemented the login api, but there is a problem with logout api. My login code is working successfully:

```php
public function login(Request $request){
    $request->validate([
        'email'=> 'required|string|email',
        'password'=> 'required|string',
        'remember_me'=> 'boolean',
    ]);

    $credentials= request(['email','password']);

    if(!Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])){

        return response()->json([
            'message'=> 'Unauthorized'
        ],401);

    }
    Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password]);
    $user=$request->user();

    $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
    $token = $tokenResult->token;

    if($request->remember_me)
        $token->expires_at= Carbon::now()->addWeek(1);

    $token->save();

    return response()->json([
        'access_token'=>$tokenResult->accessToken,
        'token_type'=>'Bearer',
        'expires_at'=>Carbon::parse($tokenResult->token->expires_at)
                        ->toDateTimeString()
    ]);
}
```

This works successfully, however, when I use the same  bearer token to revoke the token of the user I am receiving the following exception:

> *Call to a member function token() on null*

This is referring to the first line of the logout method below.

```php
public function logout(Request $request){
    $request->user()->token()->revoke();
    return response()->json([
        'message'=> 'Successfully logged out'
        ]);
}
```

Why is the output of `$request->user()` null?

Comment: what middleware does this `logout` route have assigned?

Comment: same problem as mine , accepted answer is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a token for the authenticated user, not the guest user who made the request

```php
$user= auth()->user();
$tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
$token = $tokenResult->accessToken;
```

And when revoking

```php
public function logout(Request $request)
{
  auth()->user()->token()->revoke();
  return response()->json([
      'message'=> 'Successfully logged out'
  ]);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Nope still receiving an error while revoking the token

Comment: Now that's a different problem and different question ""

Comment: I updated my answer, please don't expect Stack Overflow to fix all of your code for you, we only provide a specific answer to the specific question ^-^